# use append to add a new value to slice and the all value of slice are changed

Tags: go

**code show below:**

```
var data = make([]map[string]interface{}, 0)
var area = make(map[string]interface{})

maps_temp := []map[string]interface{}{{"id":1, "value":"a"},{"id":2, "value":"b"},{"id":3, "value":"c"}}    

for _, value := range maps_temp {
    area["id"] = value["id"]
    area["value"] = value["value"]

    data = append(data, area)
    fmt.Println("data:",data)
}
```

**The result is :**

```
data: [map[id:3 value:c] map[id:3 value:c] map[id:3 value:c]]
```

**expected result is :**

```
data: [map[id:1 value:a] map[id:2 value:b] map[id:3 value:c]]
```

why?

Comment: Please format your code correctly, indenting it with four spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you are changing the value of `area["id"]` and `area["value"]` with each iteration - the last being "id" of 3, and "value" of c. Each `map[string]interface{}` stored in `data` is pointing to the same object in memory.

You can use a composite literal to achieve the desired results.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var data = make([]map[string]interface{}, 0)
    // var area = make(map[string]interface{})

    maps_temp := []map[string]interface{}{{"id": 1, "value": "a"}, {"id": 2, "value": "b"}, {"id": 3, "value": "c"}}

    for _, value := range maps_temp {
        // area["id"] = value["id"]
        // area["value"] = value["value"]

        data = append(data, map[string]interface{}{"id": value["id"], "value": value["value"]})
    }

    fmt.Println("data:", data)
}
```

source on playground: https://play.golang.org/p/kU4eHowh8N2

Answer (score 0):

You only create one area map and are putting it in the array each time around, instead you need to create a new map for each iteration, e.g.

```
var data = make([]map[string]interface{}, 0)

maps_temp := []map[string]interface{}{{"id":1, "value":"a"},{"id":2, "value":"b"},{"id":3, "value":"c"}}    

for _, value := range maps_temp {
    area := make(map[string]interface{})
    area["id"] = value["id"]
    area["value"] = value["value"]

    data = append(data, area)
}
fmt.Println("data:",data)

results in
data: [map[value:a id:1] map[id:2 value:b] map[id:3 value:c]]
```